# Question on normal and geodesic curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, geodesic

I've worked through a problem my professor gave me on normal/geodesic curvature. I believe there was an error in his solution because in his answer he states the geodesic curvature in the following problem is zero, which I believe is wrong.

The elliptic paraboloid $S: z = x^2 + y^2$ is parametrized by $\sigma(u,v) = (u\cos(v), u\sin(v), u^2)$.

a) Find the second fundamental form of $\sigma$.

Solution:

$\mathrm{I\!I} = L\mathit{du}^2 + 2M\mathit{du dv} + N\mathit{dv}^2$

$n = \frac{\sigma_u \times \sigma_v}{||\sigma_u \times \sigma_v||} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4u^2 + 1}}(-2u\cos(v),-2u\sin(v),1)$

$L = \sigma_{uu} \cdot n = \frac{2}{\sqrt{4u^2 + 1}}$

$M = \sigma_{uv} \cdot n = 0$

$N = \sigma_{vv} \cdot n = \frac{2u^2}{\sqrt{4u^2 + 1}}$

$\mathrm{I\!I} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{4u^2 + 1}} \mathit{du^2} + \frac{2u^2}{\sqrt{4u^2 + 1}} \mathit{dv^2}$

b) Find the normal and geodesic curvatures of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ on $S$.

Solution:

$\gamma(t) = (2\cos(t), 2\sin(t), 4)$

$\dot{\gamma}(t) = (-2\sin(v), 2\cos(t), 0)$

$\ddot{\gamma}(t) = (-2\cos(v), -2\sin(v), 0)$

Find unit-speed reparametrization:

$c(s) = (2\cos(\frac{t}{2}), 2\sin(\frac{t}{2}, 4)$

$\dot{c}(s) = (-\sin(\frac{s}{2}), \cos(\frac{s}{2}), 0)$

$\ddot{c}(s) = (-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\frac{s}{2}), -\frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{s}{2}), 0)$

$n(c(s)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4(2^2) + 1}}(-4\cos(\frac{s}{2}), -4\sin(\frac{s}{2}), 1)$

Using $K_n = \ddot{\gamma}(t) \cdot n(\gamma(t))$,

$K_n = \frac{2}{\sqrt{17}}$, but since $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ is ultimately a circle of radius 2, its curvature K should be $\frac{1}{2}$. In the notes, the geodesic curvature is said to be 0, but when doing $K_g = \ddot{\gamma}(t) \cdot (n \times \dot{\gamma} (t))$, I get $K_g = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{17}}$. And when checking with the property $K^2 = K_n^2 + K_g^2$, $K_g$ should not be zero. My question is if $K_g$ is indeed not zero, what does it mean for this circle to have geodesic curvature? Does the curvature only exist because it lies on the surface? If this circle were on a cylinder of radius 2 would it still have the same geodesic curvature?

Comment: I have yet to verify your calculations although I'm fairly certain the curve has non-zero geodesic curvature. The only curves with zero geodesic curvatures are geodesics themselves, and the curve whose trace is $x^2+y^2 = 4$ is not a geodesic on $S$. The geodesic curvature is the magnitude of the non-normal component of the derivative of a curve's tangent vectors. The same curve is a geodesic on a cylinder, hence it would have zero geodesic curvature there.

Comment: Look at it geometrically. If you go around a circle at constant speed, the acceleration points towards the center of the circle. Is that vector either orthogonal to the paraboloid or tangent to it? No, it has components in both directions.